# What is the “Water of Sight” featured in Avengers: Age of Ultron?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-age-of-ultron

In *Avengers: Age of Ultron*,

> Thor jumped into *Water of Sight* to re-visit his dream. They talked something like that the pool is on every planet (or, every realm) which shows reflection of some light.

What exactly is *Water of Sight*? Anything from comics?

Comment: There is a deleted scene on the Blu-ray release that talks about the water and how it works. I'm surprised they left it out of the theater release actually.

Answer (score 17):

The "Waters of Sight" plot device appears to be inspired by the Well of Wyrd which has appeared in previous Thor titles.

The Well of Wyrd is a pool on Asgard whose waters intersect with the ley lines of [Yggdrasill](http://marvel.wikia.com/Yggdrasill). The waters of the pool have various magical properties, allowing (among other things) the ability to see events from throughout space & time. First introduced in Thor Annual #11, the pool has been mentioned numerous times throughout the comic's run, again as the "Well of Wyrd" in [Thor #347](http://marvel.wikia.com/Thor_Vol_1_347), then later called the "Well of Life" in [Thor #374](http://www.supermegamonkey.net/chronocomic/entries/thor_374.shtml).

Unfortunately, very little else is known about the Well or its properties.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

While the Water are essentially left unexplained in the final version of the movie, the deleted/extended version of the scene better explains this.

The Water of Sight that Thor and Erik visit is in a Norn Cave found somewhere on Earth.  Thor explains that there is a "reflection" of the Norn Cave found in Asgard.  The Waters are let a person speak to [The Norns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norns), who require a sacrifice of life to communicate with them. The Norns can see "what no eye can, what is, and what's to come."

Typically, the living sacrifices to the Norn do not survive, but Thor has "more life than most" to be consumed by the Norn. In the original version, Thor does not experience visions in the Water of Sight, The Norns explain the Infinite Six (or the Infinity Stones) to Erik while they simultaneously consume Thor's life.

Obviously, the final theatrical version differs. Any traces of the Norn have been removed, and the Water can now provide Thor with strange, prophetic, and expository visions.

Answer (score 0):

Phantom42 is correct in Norse mythology it's called mimir's well by which one can have a drink to obtain wisdom. This would require a substantial sacrifice. Odin once had a drink from the well and it cost him one eye.

Comment: This answer could use some fleshing out. Some links or examples of use in the comics or myths would go a long way.

Comment: I know it goes a long way but I was giving a little insight. Generally marvel follows the baseline of Norse mythology when dealing with Thor but takes its own route when it begins to go more in depth to be able to explain it's own narrative.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, well, I think the "waters of sight" will take on the role of another well, from the comics, that of the Infinity Well, which is where Thanos first gleaned the Stones' existences. And, now, in just about the exact same way, Thor is given insight into the stones. As Death and "her" realm are not likely to be portrayed, the "waters of sight' are the most likely place that Thanos would have gained the knowledge of the stones and their power.....

Comment: Do you have any quote, comic, etc to support your answer?